# Custom view not able to be combined with other views in c++20

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

I'm trying to write a custom view for concatenating ranges together. It works fine on its own, I'm able to concatenate different types of ranges and dump them to a vector together, but when I pipe it to another view like std::views::transform it breaks, as

```
error: no type named 'iterator_category' in 'struct std::iterator_traits<std::ranges::transform_view<ConcatenatedView<const std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&, const std::ranges::iota_view<int, int>&>, Concatenate_DifferentTypes_Test::TestBody()::<lambda(auto:43)> >::_Iterator<false> >'
```

The ConcatenatedView is defined as follows:

```cpp
namespace detail {

template <typename Arg, typename... Args>
struct GetFirstArgStruct {
  using Type = Arg;
};
template <typename... Args>
using GetFirstArg = GetFirstArgStruct<Args...>::Type;

// Can't be declared in the ConcatenatedView struct as explicit specialization must be in namespace scope.
template <typename... Views>
struct ConcatenatedIterator;

template <typename View, typename... RemainingViews>
struct ConcatenatedIterator<View, RemainingViews...> {
  // Required for ranges, means we can't use references, only pointers.
  ConcatenatedIterator() {}
  ConcatenatedIterator(View view, RemainingViews... rest) : view_{view}, iter_{view_.begin()}, rest_(rest...) {}

  bool IsEnd() const {
    if (iter_ == view_.end()) return rest_.IsEnd();
    return false;
  }

  // This returns a copy. We could use decltype(auto), but would need to ensure that all views return either
  // values or references.
  auto operator*() const {
    if constexpr (sizeof...(RemainingViews) != 0) {
      if (iter_ == view_.end()) return *rest_;
    }
    return *iter_;
  }

  ConcatenatedIterator& operator++() {
    if (iter_ == view_.end()) {
      if constexpr (sizeof...(RemainingViews) != 0) ++rest_;
    } else {
      ++iter_;
    }
    return *this;
  }

 private:
  friend bool operator==(const ConcatenatedIterator&, const ConcatenatedIterator&) = default;

  View view_;
  std::ranges::iterator_t<View> iter_;
  ConcatenatedIterator<RemainingViews...> rest_;
};

template <>
struct ConcatenatedIterator<> {
  bool IsEnd() const { return true; }
};

}  // namespace detail

template <std::ranges::range... Ranges>
struct ConcatenatedView : public std::ranges::view_interface<ConcatenatedView<Ranges...>> {
 public:
  struct Sentinel {};

  template <std::ranges::view... Views>
  struct Iterator {
    using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using value_type = std::ranges::range_value_t<detail::GetFirstArg<Views...>>;
    using pointer = value_type*;
    using reference = value_type&;

    Iterator() {}  // Requirement for ranges.
    Iterator(Views... views) : iter_(views...) {}

    decltype(auto) operator*() const { return *iter_; }

    Iterator& operator++() {
      ++iter_;
      return *this;
    }

    Iterator operator++(int) {
      Iterator tmp = *this;
      ++(*this);
      return tmp;
    }

    // TODO: Support sized view when all the ranges are sized.

   private:
    friend bool operator==(const Iterator& it, Sentinel) { return it.iter_.IsEnd(); }
    friend bool operator==(const Iterator&, const Iterator&) = default;

    detail::ConcatenatedIterator<Views...> iter_;
  };

  using IterT = Iterator<decltype(std::ranges::views::all(std::forward<Ranges>(std::declval<Ranges&&>())))...>;

  ConcatenatedView() {}  // Required for a view.
  ConcatenatedView(Ranges&&... ranges) : views_(std::ranges::views::all(std::forward<Ranges>(ranges))...) {}

  IterT begin() const { return std::make_from_tuple<IterT>(views_); }
  Sentinel end() const { return {}; };

 private:
  std::tuple<decltype(std::ranges::views::all(std::forward<Ranges>(std::declval<Ranges&&>())))...> views_;
};

template <std::ranges::range... Ranges>
ConcatenatedView<Ranges...> Concatenate(Ranges&&... ranges) {
  return {std::forward<Ranges>(ranges)...};
}
```

Trying to run:

```cpp
  const auto vector = std::vector{1, 2, 3};
  const auto iota = std::views::iota(4, 7);
  const auto concat =
      Concatenate(vector, iota) | std::views::common | std::views::transform([](const auto i) { return i + 1; });
  auto result = std::vector<std::ranges::range_value_t<decltype(concat)>>{};
  result.insert(result.end(), concat.begin(), concat.end());
```

Adding a `std::views::common` between my custom view and the transform view does not help either.

I notice in the `std::views::transform` documentation that

```
iterator_category: Not defined if Base does not model forward_range.
```

But I believe my view models a forward range, as

```cpp
  static_assert(
      std::derived_from<std::iterator_traits<decltype(c.begin())>::iterator_category, std::forward_iterator_tag> ==
      true);
```

Comment: Perhaps you should assert on `std::ranges::forward_range` instead of on `iterator_category` being derived from `forward_iterator_tag`?

Comment: `concat_view` is actually a very complex view, which contains many tricky issues. You can learn about related concerns and reference implementations from the [latest P2542 paper](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2023/p2542r4.html) just released this month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It always helps to start with a simpler problem. Let's just concatenate one thing without any pipes:

```cpp
auto vector = std::vector{1, 2, 3};
auto concat = Concatenate(vector);
```

Now, the way to validate that an iterator is a `forward_iterator` is do directly assert that, not to simply check the category (there are a lot more requirements for an iterator than simply the category):

```cpp
static_assert(std::forward_iterator<decltype(concat.begin())>);
```

When you do so, you'll see that you haven't satisfied some requirements. For instance, equality comparison doesn't work. This is both because `ConcatenatedIterator<>` (the recursive base case) isn't comparable and also because `ConcatenatedIterator<View, RemainingViews...>` has a member `View` that `operator==` is trying to compare (a view need not be equality-comparable, and it seems highly questionable to even attempt to do so in this context... also the iterator should definitely not have a view member - not all views have iterator stability on move, so just moving that iterator could invalidate it).

Once you fix that, the `forward_iterator` assertion will tell you the next operation you're missing, and so forth. Keep iterating until the assertion compiles, and then it'll work.

---

One other thing I have to note:

```cpp
std::tuple<decltype(std::ranges::views::all(std::forward<Ranges>(std::declval<Ranges&&>())))...> views_;
```

1. `std::declval<T&&>()` is the same thing as `std::declval<T>()`
2. `std::forward<T>(std::declval<T>())` is the same thing as `std::declval<T>()`
3. `std::ranges::views::meow` is the same thing as `std::views::meow`
4. Getting the type of a viewable range, `decltype(std::views::all(x))`, has a dedicated alias template named `std::views::all_t`. This is especially convenient here since what we to begin with is a type.

Hence:

```cpp
std::tuple<std::views::all_t<Ranges>...> views_;
```

---

Also, this iterator implementation is inefficient. If you're concatenating `N` ranges together, then getting elements from the first range is requires 1 branch but getting elements from the 5th range... requires 5 branches (we need to check if each iterator before us is done yet). Same for the rest of the operations.

The typical way to implement concatenation is that the iterator is holding a `variant<iterator_t<R>...>` - that way dereference is always just one variant visit, increment is one visit and a branch (we might have multiple branches if we have a lot of empty ranges to skip, but typically just one branch), etc.